# An X is an X is an X

Tags: meaning, etymology, expressions

What is the meaning of the expression "An *X* is an *X* is an *X*"?
Judging from the sentences I found this expression in I'd say it means "every *X* is pretty much the same".

How did this expression originate? It is not exactly easy to google it given its structure.

Comment: Could this come from [Gertrude Stein's poem 'Sacred Emily'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rose_is_a_rose_is_a_rose_is_a_rose): "A rose is a rose is a rose"?

Comment: I think it's more common as _An X is an X is an X_ as in [A man is a man is a man](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2838610/). The description of that movies gives a clue : _A[...] Comedy proving that a Man is a Man, regardless of the colour of his skin_

Comment: @oerkelens, you're right, my bad

Comment: Yep, as the dupe says, comes from Stein's "rose is a rose is a rose" which almost certainly comes from Shakey's "A rose by any other name would smell as sweet".